# MyEclipse 2016 Debugger Using Wrong Version of Code

Tags: java, debugging, websphere, myeclipse

I just updated to MyEclipse 2016, and I am having some issues getting my code to debug.

I wrote some changes in a java file and am trying to debug them on my websphere application server, but I noticed the debugger wasn't following the code at all. After a little investigation it turns out that I'm on V5 of the code, but the debugger is running V4 of the code.

I've tried going into the menu at

Run -> Debug Configurations... -> (Select My Server) -> Source

and changing the sources listed in here to just the workspace projects, but the debugger still goes through the old version of the code.

I'm at a loss and don't know what to do to get the debugger to pick up the right code. Does anybody have any suggestions I could try to get my debugger to pick up the new version of my code?

Edit: Forgot to include, Project --> Build Automatically is checked in the menus, and I have tried manually cleaning this a few times myself as well.

Comment: Could you clean up your Workspace and rebuild it?

Comment: Forgot to include, Project --> Build Automatically is checked in the menus, and I have tried manually cleaning this a few times myself as well.

Comment: Just to be clear; you are debugging code on the server and the debugger is actually displaying V5 code but stepping through V4 code? Or are you saying that the debugger is displaying V4 source but actually stepping through V5 code? Also, does V4/V5 refer to your project's code or to some jars that your project is using?

Comment: V4/V5 refers to my project's code. While I am seeing V5 of the code in MyEclipse, it's not following along with the V5 of the code at all.  By watching the line numbers it's stepping through, and the variables being made in debugger, I can tell that it is actually going through V4 of the code instead,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your last comment, this means that the V4 code is actually executing on the server. The debugger is not executing anything; it is the server that is executing the code. So you have the wrong version deployed, somehow. Try a clean on the server, to remove any deployments and then re-deploy your project.

Answer (score 0):

Given what everybody had said I checked into the deployment to the server.  Looks like I had a WAR deployed to my server, when there is actually an EAR I can deploy to the server which includes the WAR I had deployed.  Apparently doing just the WAR broke things, but deploying the EAR seemed to fix it all.  Thank you all for the input though, definitely helped me get to the root of the issue!

Comment: So you might consider either marking the answer as accepted or at least clicking the up arrow to mark it as useful. Thanks.

Comment: My mistake. Still getting used to actually posting on stack overflow. Believe i have accepted it as the answer now. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Actually, I was thinking more about my answer (upvote and/or accept), since it helped you find the solution. But, no matter.

Comment: It is fixed. Thanks for jogging my memory!